# How to insert bulk data into database at a time?

Tags: mysql

I've created a stored procedure. I fetch cursor with huge amount of data(around 1L rows).
After that I call another procedure in it to do all calculations related to needed data.
I create temporary table and try to insert this calculated data in it. But it takes too long
about 9.5 mins.
I want to know how to insert bulk data by using least "INSERT" queries as 1L insert queries cause poorest performance. Can anyone help me??

Comment: @Jack 1L = 1 Lakh = 100,000 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following SQL statement for bulk insert:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (A, B, C, D) VALUES
(1,1,1,1),
(2,2,2,2),
(3,3,3,3),
(4,4,4,4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague but you can BULK load data into mysql using

```
load data infile...
```

Check the following links:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html
- [MySQL load data infile - acceleration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463602/mysql-load-data-infile-acceleration/2504211#2504211)

If you need to process the data during the load it might be better to first bulk load the data into a temporary table then run some stored procedures against it which process and populate your main tables.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

also you can insert record to in-memory table.after complete inserting to in-memory table following code for insert many rows from in-memory table.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (A, B, C, D)
SELECT A,B,C,D FROM INMEMORY_TABLE

DELETE FROM INMEMORY_TABLE
```