# Load csv files into mysql faster or in parallel

Tags: mysql, bash, centos, centos7

I have a mysql table which contains a Primary auto_increment key.

I have 500 csv files, each about 3gb worth of data and the bulk of the data in one column.

Currently I'm loading the files into mysql using:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /files/*.csv
do
    mysql -e "load data local infile '$f' into table myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '\"' escaped by '\"' IGNORE 1 LINES"  -u user -ppass
done
```

Are there any ways to improve performance? Maybe removing the primary key while inserting and then adding it afterwards? Or is there a way to insert in parallel instead of one file at a time?

Comment: You could try looping through each line and executing an insert for each line. It may or may not perform better than a one off load but it may be worth a go.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463602/mysql-load-data-infile-acceleration

Comment: Also, as far as inserting in parallel, I don't think it would help much since the  processing steps will be the same as far as the engine goes, i.e. Same workload going through the same channel, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

The new MySQL Shell as of version 5.0.17 has a parallel bulk loader for CSV, TSV, and JSON files.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Maybe a link to what exactly is it/how to use it?

Comment: See https://elephantdolphin.blogspot.com/2019/08/parallel-table-importer-in-mysql-shell.html for an example of using the new parallel bulk loader utility in the MySQL Shell