# Why BULK insert gives syntax error of expecting eof

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, bulkinsert

I want to insert large number of rows from csv into sql database but when I use the code below

```
BULK INSERT Sales
FROM 'C:\1500000 Sales Records.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n' );
```

It gives the following error

BULK is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'
I am using MYSQL8.0 DB and first I created table with create table command and then I was trying to bulk insert the data from csv

Comment: is this code part of a script with others  commands??  and which db you are really using ??  which version?

Comment: I am using MYSQL8.0 DB and first I created table with create table command and then I was trying to bulk insert the data from csv

Comment: The mysql version of bulk insert is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: But it is slow. I tried inserting 400k+ rows and it took more than 4 hours to insert

Comment: For improving performance of load data refer this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463602/mysql-load-data-infile-acceleration