# Why LOAD DATA INFILE MYSQL is slow

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, bulkinsert

I tried inserting 400k+ rows and it took more than 4 hours to insert using LOAD DATA INFILE from a csv file.

400k+ rows and 18 columns with variable like int, longtext, varchar.

Comment: How much data are you inserting into "longtext" columns? Are there triggers, foreign keys, indexes? And are you doing this locally on the server or using `LOCAL INFILE`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL load data infile - acceleration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463602/mysql-load-data-infile-acceleration)

Comment: Lot of data in one longtext column i.e. one paragraph. there are foreign keys which I disable during data import. I am doing it using load data infile. not local infile